# How can I match a Decoder's input to a Pretrained Resnet18 Encoder?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to build a custom Decoder with skip connections to run with a pretrained Resnet18 Encoder for Image Segmentation task. The total number of classes are 150.

The Resnet18 Encoder has fc output of 512. In order to match the Encoder's output to Decoder's input, I am trying to set the Conv layers of Decoder such that it matches the output from Encoder i.e [151, 512, 1, 1]. However, no matter what combination of layers I make, I am not able to match the input and output tensors.

Here is the relevant part of Decoder Code

```
class ResNet18Transpose(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, transblock, layers, num_classes=150):
        self.inplanes = 512
        super(ResNet18Transpose, self).__init__()
        
        self.deconv1 = self._make_transpose(transblock, 256 * transblock.expansion, layers[0], stride=2)
        self.deconv2 = self._make_transpose(transblock, 128 * transblock.expansion, layers[1], stride=2)
        self.deconv3 = self._make_transpose(transblock, 64 * transblock.expansion, layers[2], stride=2)
        self.deconv4 = self._make_transpose(transblock, 32 * transblock.expansion, layers[3], stride=2)
        

        self.skip0 = self._make_skip_layer(64, 64 * transblock.expansion)
        self.skip1 = self._make_skip_layer(128, 64 * transblock.expansion)
        self.skip2 = self._make_skip_layer(256, 64 * transblock.expansion)
        self.skip3 = self._make_skip_layer(512, 128 * transblock.expansion)
        
        self.inplanes = 64
        self.final_conv = self._make_transpose(transblock, 64 * transblock.expansion, 3)
        
        self.final_deconv = nn.ConvTranspose2d(self.inplanes * transblock.expansion, num_classes, kernel_size=2,
                                               stride=2, padding=0, bias=True)
        
        self.out6_conv = nn.Conv2d(1024, num_classes, kernel_size=1, stride=1, bias=True)
        self.out5_conv = nn.Conv2d(128 * transblock.expansion, num_classes, kernel_size=1, stride=1, bias=True)
        self.out4_conv = nn.Conv2d(128 * transblock.expansion, num_classes, kernel_size=1, stride=1, bias=True)
        self.out3_conv = nn.Conv2d(64 * transblock.expansion, num_classes, kernel_size=1, stride=1, bias=True)
        self.out2_conv = nn.Conv2d(32 * transblock.expansion, num_classes, kernel_size=1, stride=1, bias=True)
        
        for m in self.modules():
            if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
                n = m.kernel_size[0] * m.kernel_size[1] * m.out_channels
                m.weight.data.normal_(0, math.sqrt(2. / n))
            elif isinstance(m, nn.ConvTranspose2d):
                n = m.kernel_size[0] * m.kernel_size[1] * m.out_channels
                m.weight.data.normal_(0, math.sqrt(2. / n))
            elif isinstance(m, SynchronizedBatchNorm2d):
                m.weight.data.fill_(1)
                m.bias.data.zero_()
```

The forward block for Decoder is as follows:

```
def forward(self, x, labels=None, sparse_mode=False, use_skip=True):
        [in0, in1, in2, in3, in4] = x
        if labels:
            [lab0, lab1, lab2, lab3, lab4] = labels

        out6 = self.out6_conv(in4)
        
        if sparse_mode:
            if labels:
                mask4 = (lab4==0).unsqueeze(1).repeat(1,in4.shape[1],1,1).type(in4.dtype)
            else:
                mask4 = (torch.argmax(out6, dim=1)==0).unsqueeze(1).repeat(1,in4.shape[1],1,1).type(in4.dtype)
            in4 = in4 * mask4

        # upsample 1
        x = self.deconv1(in4)
        out5 = self.out5_conv(x)
        
        if sparse_mode:
            if labels:
                mask3 = (lab3==0).unsqueeze(1).repeat(1,in3.shape[1],1,1).type(in3.dtype)
            else:
                mask3 = (torch.argmax(out5, dim=1)==0).unsqueeze(1).repeat(1,in3.shape[1],1,1).type(in3.dtype)
            in3 = in3 * mask3

        if use_skip:
            x = x + self.skip3(in3)
        
        # upsample 2
        x = self.deconv2(x)
        out4 = self.out4_conv(x)
        
        if sparse_mode:
            if labels:
                mask2 = (lab2==0).unsqueeze(1).repeat(1,in2.shape[1],1,1).type(in2.dtype)
            else:
                mask2 = (torch.argmax(out4, dim=1)==0).unsqueeze(1).repeat(1,in2.shape[1],1,1).type(in2.dtype)
            in2 = in2 * mask2

        if use_skip:
            x = x + self.skip2(in2)
        
        # upsample 3
        x = self.deconv3(x)
        out3 = self.out3_conv(x)
        
        if sparse_mode:
            if labels:
                mask1 = (lab1==0).unsqueeze(1).repeat(1,in1.shape[1],1,1).type(in1.dtype)
            else:
                mask1 = (torch.argmax(out3, dim=1)==0).unsqueeze(1).repeat(1,in1.shape[1],1,1).type(in1.dtype)
            in1 = in1 * mask1

        if use_skip:
            x = x + self.skip1(in1)
        
        # upsample 4
        x = self.deconv4(x)
        out2 = self.out2_conv(x)
        
        if sparse_mode:
            if labels:
                mask0 = (lab0==0).unsqueeze(1).repeat(1,in0.shape[1],1,1).type(in0.dtype)
            else:
                mask0 = (torch.argmax(out2, dim=1)==0).unsqueeze(1).repeat(1,in0.shape[1],1,1).type(in0.dtype)
            in0 = in0 * mask0

        if use_skip:
            x = x + self.skip0(in0)
        
        # final
        x = self.final_conv(x)
        out1 = self.final_deconv(x)

        return [out6, out5, out4, out3, out2, out1]
```

I get the following error:

```
 File "/project/xfu/aamir/Golden-QGN/models/resnet.py", line 447, in forward
    out6 = self.out6_conv(in4)
  File "/project/xfu/aamir/anaconda3/envs/QGN/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 722, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/project/xfu/aamir/anaconda3/envs/QGN/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 419, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight)
  File "/project/xfu/aamir/anaconda3/envs/QGN/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 415, in _conv_forward
    return F.conv2d(input, weight, self.bias, self.stride,
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [151, 1024, 1, 1], expected input[8, 512, 8, 8] to have 1024 channels, but got 512 channels instead
Exception in thread Thread-1:
```

If I change the Decoder Layers as follows:

```
self.out6_conv = nn.Conv2d(512, num_classes, kernel_size=1, stride=1, bias=True)
        self.out5_conv = nn.Conv2d(256 * transblock.expansion, num_classes, kernel_size=1, stride=1, bias=True)
        self.out4_conv = nn.Conv2d(128 * transblock.expansion, num_classes, kernel_size=1, stride=1, bias=True)
        self.out3_conv = nn.Conv2d(64 * transblock.expansion, num_classes, kernel_size=1, stride=1, bias=True)
        self.out2_conv = nn.Conv2d(32 * transblock.expansion, num_classes, kernel_size=1, stride=1, bias=True)
```

I get the followng error. Note that the input tensor has also changed.

```
 File "/project/xfu/aamir/anaconda3/envs/QGN/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 415, in _conv_forward
    return F.conv2d(input, weight, self.bias, self.stride,
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 64, 3, 3], expected input[8, 32, 128, 128] to have 64 channels, but got 32 channels instead
```

I also tried altering the Resnet18 Encoder's fc output to 1024 instead of 512 as follows:

```
def resnet18(pretrained=False, **kwargs):
    """Constructs a ResNet-18 model.
    Args:
        pretrained (bool): If True, returns a model pre-trained on ImageNet
    """
    model = ResNet(BasicBlock, [2, 2, 2, 2], **kwargs)
    if pretrained:
        model.load_state_dict(load_url(model_urls['resnet18']))   
        model.fc = torch.nn.Linear(1024, 150)
    return model
```

But nothing seems to work. I also could not find a skip connections based decoder for resnet18 on github / internet. Any help will be appreciated.

**NOTE:** I only want to work on Resnet18. Also the images being input to the network through dataloader are working perfectly fine with a Resnet50 Encoder + Custom Decoder. I also tried changing crop size from 0 to 128 to 256 to 512 but in vain.

Here is the code that is being run in models.py for image segmentation. I tried using the set_trace() method to debug the code. The code stops running just before the `(pred, pred_quad) = self.decoder(fmap, labels_scaled)` line in following code

```
class SegmentationModule(SegmentationModuleBase):
    
    def __init__(self, net_enc, net_dec, crit, deep_sup_scale=None, quad_sup=False, running_avg_param=0.99):
        super(SegmentationModule, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = net_enc
        self.decoder = net_dec
        self.crit = crit
        if deep_sup_scale:
          if deep_sup_scale < 0:
              self.adapt_weights = True
              self.running_avg_param = running_avg_param
              deep_sup_scale = 1
          else:
              self.adapt_weights = False
          self.loss_weights = [(deep_sup_scale**(i+1)) for i in range(5)]
        self.quad_sup = quad_sup
            
    def forward(self, feed_dict, *, segSize=None):
        inputs = feed_dict['img_data'].cuda()
        if segSize is None: # training
            labels_orig_scale = feed_dict['seg_label_0'].cuda()             
            labels_scaled = []
            fmap = self.encoder(inputs, return_feature_maps=True)
            if self.quad_sup:
                labels_scaled.append(feed_dict['seg_label_1'].cuda())
                labels_scaled.append(feed_dict['seg_label_2'].cuda())
                labels_scaled.append(feed_dict['seg_label_3'].cuda())
                labels_scaled.append(feed_dict['seg_label_4'].cuda())
                labels_scaled.append(feed_dict['seg_label_5'].cuda())
                (pred, pred_quad) = self.decoder(fmap, labels_scaled)
            else:
                pred = self.decoder(fmap)
            loss = self.crit(pred, labels_orig_scale)
            if self.quad_sup:
                loss_orig = loss
                for i in range(len(pred_quad)):
                    loss_quad = self.crit(pred_quad[i], labels_scaled[i])
                    loss = loss + loss_quad * self.loss_weights[i]
                    if self.adapt_weights:
                        self.loss_weights[i] = self.running_avg_param * self.loss_weights[i] + \
                        (1 - self.running_avg_param) * (loss_quad/loss_orig).data.cpu().numpy()

            acc = self.pixel_acc(pred, labels_orig_scale, self.quad_sup)
            return loss, acc
        else: # inference
            if 'qtree' in feed_dict:
                labels_scaled = [feed_dict['qtree'][l].cuda() for l in range(1,6)]                
            else:
                labels_scaled = None
            pred = self.decoder(self.encoder(inputs, return_feature_maps=True), labels_scaled, segSize=segSize)
            return pred
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is how I resolved the error.

1. Disabled the skip connections. Not sure why the decoder doesnt work with skip connections.
2. I had given incorrect layers [6, 3, 4, 3] input to Decoder. i.e for Resnet18 the layers should be [2,2,2,2]